# R error: unsupported type passed to argument 'data' when using 'dygraphs' package

Tags: r, dygraphs

The `dygraph_data` is like this:

```
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2014 
Frequency = 1 

      Demersal   Pelagic   Shellfish
2000 151331280   15250000  11118158
2001 123783748   4745089   8763
2002 111344651   6684587   89435
2003 87037703    48474713  890285
2004 87662990    73179786  95277201
2005 99651422    88985214  100725092
2006 112457611   64469744  130364550
2007 109166907   71420558  147927361
2008 116488637   71498653  139568778
2009 125169397   87299457  126979010
2010 130428225   101416203 134191700
2011 130752956   108004962 140602688
2012 120596070   76703847  134106346
2013 122822166   79487818  118983904
2014 127291732   109565488 131276559

dygraph(dygraph_data) # this gives an error as described below...
```

And when I apply `dygraph_data` to `dygraph`:

```
dygraph(dygraph_data)
```

It gives the following error:

> Error in dygraph(dygraph_data) : Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'.

This is a yearly data, but when the data is monthly, such problem would not happen. Why?

Answer (score 3):

I think your time serie have a wrong format for the date. you have to convert it with as.xts(timeSerie object) from xts library.
for example:

```
library(xts)
```

first you create your time serie and convert it with as.xts()

```
    antenne <- as.xts(ts(start = c(1991), end=c(2009),
  data = c(6,6,88,200,657,903,1381,3163,3587,4511,4834,4978,5375,6381,7246,7911,
8508,9128,9538)))
antenne
1991-01-01    6
1992-01-01    6
1993-01-01   88
1994-01-01  200
1995-01-01  657
1996-01-01  903
1997-01-01 1381
1998-01-01 3163
1999-01-01 3587
2000-01-01 4511
2001-01-01 4834
2002-01-01 4978
2003-01-01 5375
2004-01-01 6381
2005-01-01 7246
2006-01-01 7911
2007-01-01 8508
2008-01-01 9128
2009-01-01 9538
```

you see now the right format for the date: year-month-day. not only the year.  dygraph expect a right format for the date.